# How to join tables from IdentityDbContext and ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-identity

How do I join AspNetUsers to my tables where Email is Confirmed from AspNetUsers table

**Selecting users from table AspNetUsers where email is confirmed**

```
var context = new IdentityDbContext();
var users = context.Users.Where(d => d.EmailConfirmed == true).Select(d => d.Id).ToList();
```

**My table**

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
UserAccountListViewModel model = new UserAccountListViewModel();
model.UserAccounts = db.UserAccounts.ToList();
```

Comment: You are trying to  get the `UserAcccounts` which are exists in `users` list, isn't it?

Comment: @TanvirArjel yes sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
UserAccountListViewModel model = new UserAccountListViewModel();

model.UserAccounts = db.UserAccounts.Where(ua => users.Contains(ua.Id)).ToList(); // Here `ua.Id` is the column of `UserAccount` table that you are comparing against the Id of Users table.
```